# Angular 6 on ng serve change localhost:4200 to domain:name

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

In angular 6 we use ng serve to start angular server with ng server --open,  den in browser we get http://localhost:4200,

What I want :-
When I ng serve the angular 6 project, should show directly go to http://domain-name.com

So I want to run angular project directly to domain name can it be possible.

On FRESH PROJECT

Comment: Usually it shouldn't matter ;) it will change anyway when deploy to a specific domain

Comment: My senior's want that when I ng serve it should go to a particular url (domain name url).  When I use ng serve or make changes in project.@Vaseline davidov

Comment: First of all the title is misleading it should say domain-name.com as after colon only port number can come and not alphabets. Secondly, doing ng serve on ur local env will show up localhost only. Even if you change it to point to a remote hosted domain, your code will still be the old one on the remote host. You will have to follow the answer given by Sachin Shah below. But in the scenario were you are on a host server itself doing the ng serve --open and not ng server, then your question seems suitable. Let us know your exact use case.

Answer (score 1):

`ng serve --open` is only for local development purpose - it is not a matter, it can be changed when you deploy your project

`ng build --prod --deploy-url=[bind the domain url]`

This will provide you the build based on the domain you specified and you can deploy your builds in the specific location

To change the `ng serve` port you can use `ng serve --open --port=4500` any port id specified.

Comment: In order to avoid CORS domain issues in local., I'm trying to change my angular domain name to point API domains. Is there any changes to change it to the needed domain name?

Answer (score 0):

For run project on live domain. Follow this steps.

Step 1: Make a build with this command. `ng build --prod`.

Step 2: In Dist/index.html , Update base URL with your domain name.

Step 3: Make ZIP file of dist folder.

Step 4: Copy and paste ZIP folder into you respective server. you can use filezilla for that.

Step 5: Unzip folder.

Step 6: Update dist folder name to your project folder name.

Step 7: Check on browser.

Comment: Can we just change localhost to my domain-name  while using ng serve,  in angular.json

Comment: @AbhinavSharma That you have to try , I haven't tried in that way. You can try and let me know it works or not.. :D

Comment: It will work perfectly but I want when I write ng serve it should open to my testing server domain name

Comment: I want to change the environment of localhost to testing domain name

Comment: @AbhinavSharma For update environment you can use one config file and just enable and disable line. I mean put static code and use one at a time.